# My module system design is trying to use typenames before their declaration. How can I design better module layout?

Tags: c++, c++17, typename

I'm trying to create module system for my game engine, but I have encountered a problem. There are two classes `Module` and `ModuleFactory`. `ModuleFactory` class stores `Module` class and all it's components. I want the `Module` class to be able to specify what parameters it needs to be registered, but you can't use `typenames` before they have been defined.

---

`ModuleFactory` class:

```cpp
template<typename Base, typename TCreateValue, typename ... Args>
class ModuleFactory {
public:
    using TRegistryMap = std::unordered_map<TypeId, TCreateValue>;

    static TRegistryMap &ModuleRegistry() {
        static TRegistryMap registry;
        return registry;
    }

    template<typename T>
    class Registry : public Base {
    public:
        static T* Get() {
            return moduleInstance;
        }

    protected:
        static bool Register(Args ... args) {
            ModuleFactory::Registry()[TypeInfo<Base>::template GetTypeId<T>()] = {[]() {
                moduleInstance = new T();

                return std::unique_ptr<Base>(moduleInstance);
            }, args...};

            return true;
        };

        inline static T *moduleInstance = nullptr;
    };
};
```

---

`Module` class:

```cpp
class Module : public ModuleFactory<Module, Module::TCreateValue, Module::Stage> { 
//You can't use TCreateValue and Stage before their declaration, so this throws error.
public:
    enum class Stage : uint8_t {
        Never, Always, Pre, Tick, Post, Render
    };

    class TCreateValue {
    public:
        std::function<std::unique_ptr<Module>()> create;
        Stage stage;
    };
    
};
```

---

Just `SomeClass`:

```cpp
class SomeClass : public Module::Registry<SomeClass> {
    inline static bool Registered = Register(Stage::Always);
};
```

As I said before I want the `Module` class to be able to set what parameters it needs for it's registartion. Any ideas on how can I solve this problem or redesign my module layout and still achieve the same goal. Only idea I have is to move `TCreateValue` and `Stage` outside of `Module` class, but I don't want to have mess in my code.

Comment: C++20 now has a *module system*, which is completely unrelated to your code. Therefore, I think it is confusing to use that wording in your question.

Comment: I'm not native speaker so it is bit hard for me to make more complex sentences.

Comment: Your sentences are good enough, no worry. I was just pointing out that there is a naming clash that you could not guess if you use C++17.

Comment: @xarxarx: This question is... imprecise. You speak frequently about things like "parameters," "modules," and "components", but it's not clear what you mean by those things. Like, when you say that a "module" has "components", are you referring to class members or something else? When you say that a "module" has "parameters", are you talking about the parameters to a class constructor or do you mean something else?

Comment: Module is the main module class. ModuleFactory is the base module class which stores module. By parameters I mean template parameters that are then use in the Register function.